# error in parsing xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-2

I have following code snippet:

```
 var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
  settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

reader = XmlReader.Create(url, settings);

try
{
    doc.Load(reader);   // Error here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

where url is :

http://localhost.:38734/mysubdir/data.xml

But I get error :

```
System.Xml.XmlException: Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 111, position 20.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleGeneralEntityReference(String name, Boolean isInAttributeValue, Boolean pushFakeEntityIfNullResolver, Int32 entityStartLinePos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleEntityReference(Boolean isInAttributeValue, EntityExpandType expandType, Int32& charRefEndPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at EnviroTracker.Feed.FeedReader.Get(String url, String username, String password) in c:\FeedReader.cs:line


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server host="IPC_Server_Room" address="10.10.50.22" name="RSM" owl-version="CB_705" product-version="3.5.0" pversion="2.00" mac-address="00:19:85:E0:20:DF" datetime="Tue, 03/01/11 23:53:01" company="Geist Manufacturing" company-url="http://www.abc.com" support-email="support@geistmfg.com" support-phone="800.432.3219" console-id="chh" tempunit="F" uptime="238871">
  <cameras>
  </cameras>
  <devices>
    <device id="0145B5D613000098" name="IPC_Server_Room" type="GeistGoos" available="1" index="0">
      <field key="TempC" value="24.86" niceName="Temperature (C)" min="-40.0" max="123.8" type="0" />
      <field key="TempF" value="76.74" niceName="Temperature (F)" min="-40.0" max="254.8" type="2" />
      <field key="Humidity" value="32" niceName="Relative Humidity" min="0.0" max="100.0" type="2" />
      <field key="DewPtC" value="7.0" niceName="Dew Point (C)" min="-40.0" max="123.8" type="0" />
      <field key="DewPtF" value="44.7" niceName="Dew Point (F)" min="-40.0" max="254.8" type="2" />
      <field key="Light" value="3" niceName="Light Level" min="1.0" max="100.0" type="2" />
      <field key="Airflow" value="23" niceName="Air Flow" min="0.0" max="100.0" type="2" />
      <field key="Sound" value="3" niceName="Sound Level" min="0.0" max="99.0" type="2" />
      <field key="IO1" value="98" niceName="Power" min="0.0" max="99.0" type="2" />
      <field key="IO2" value="97" niceName="Door Contact" min="0.0" max="99.0" type="2" />
      <field key="IO3" value="99" niceName="Water Snake" min="0.0" max="99.0" type="2" />
      <field key="Volts" value="122.8" niceName="Volts" min="0.0" max="275.0" type="2" />
      <field key="Volt-Pk" value="122.9" niceName="Volts (Peak)" min="0.0" max="275.0" type="2" />
    </device>
  </devices>
  <alarms>
  </alarms>
</server>
```

How can I fix it

Comment: @DotNetSparrow: You cannot post a link to localhost to other users on the internet. This url refers to your own local development machine only.

Comment: Can you post the XML you are trying to load

Comment: The OP exemplified the link, I believe, so we can see he is accessing a URL, not a file.

Comment: @Brain: I am working locally so I sent you the localhostlink. @Swaff: I have modified the question. Please find the xml.

Comment: Just wondering if you have nbsp in your XML rather than &nbsp;

Comment: @Swaff. Now I dont have nbsp in xml

Comment: the error says it's line 111 in the xml, it seems the posted xml doesn't have so many lines

Comment: @DotnetSparrow In your question you quote your URL as being [http://localhost.:38734/mysubdir/data.xml](http://localhost.:38734/mysubdir/data.xml). I was just wondering if this is the same in your application, because it includes an extra dot after localhost.

Comment: @Swaff: Extra dot was for fiddler. I tried without it and same error.

Comment: @Rober: I have posted all the xml

Comment: @DotnetSparrow Can you post your XmlSettings code as well please.

Comment: @Swaff: Please see the updated code. I have added settings in question

Comment: @DotnetSparrow I have just created an application using your code and the XML which I hosted on my local IIS. It runs absolutely fine making me think that the XML you are sharing is different as suggested above by @Robert

Comment: @Swaff: did you use XmDocument or reader ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow I used: `var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"http://localhost/one/test.xml", settings);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            try
            {
                doc.Load(reader);   // Error here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }` I did this having saved your posted xml to a file called test.xml.

Comment: @Swaff: I useed XmlReader.Create(Server.mappath(~/TestDevice/data.xml"),settings); and it worked I am not sure why it is not working with http://localhost:38734/mysubdir/data.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading it with XmlDocument. XmlDocument can understand some XMLs that XmlReader can't. Don't know why this is so, but this is a fact from my practice. If XmlDocument also doesn't understand your XML, then your XML is composed incorrectly.

Comment: I need to load xml from url. can I use Xmldocument with url ?

Comment: O am using xmldocument .load but it is very very slow with url. any suggestion why it is not working with reader?

Comment: XmlReader is ofcourse much faster, but it doesn't understand all XMLs that XmlDocument understands. You can also use XDocument for your needs.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use Xmldoc or Xdoc in my case from url and settings given above ?